# Class 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher' not found in /var/www/html/site/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php on line 221

Tags: php, solr, zend-framework2, solarium

I am trying to use the [Solarium](https://github.com/Ewgo/SolariumModule) library with Zend Framework 2

- I put the library in external folder of my zend2 application
- I add this line to my `Module.php`:

  `'Solarium' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../library/Solarium'),`
- I add the config lines for host, port,.... to my application config
- I create an instance and client example to do select requests but I get this error:

> Class 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher' not found in /var/www/html/library/site/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php on line 221

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second bullet point? Where do you add that line? Also: you're using Composer, right?

Comment: Use composer to install it will all the dependencies